# Change block configuration before render the block programmatically

Tags: 7, blocks, navigation, configuration

I have a view that display some nodes and some of this nodes have a menu voice connected to them with sub menus.

main menu:
-node 1  [mid:407]
--node 2
--node 3
-node 4  [mid:219]
--node 5

I want my views display something like:

node 1 data + the submenu
--node 2
--node 3

node 4 data + the submenu
--node 5

I installed the module [menu_block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) and I created a block that display all the child of a menu voice and I tryed to change the 'parent' setting it programmatically and display the block like this:

```
$block = block_load('menu_block', 1);
$render_array = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
print_r($render_array['menu_block_1']['#config']);

$render_array['menu_block_1']['#config']['parent'] = 'main-menu:219';
$render_array['menu_block_1']['#config']['parent_mlid'] = 219;
print_r($render_array['menu_block_1']['#config']);

$output = drupal_render($render_array);
print $output;
```

the 2 output of the print_r are

```
Array
(
    [parent] => main-menu:407
    [title_link] => 0
    [admin_title] => 
    [level] => 1
    [follow] => 0
    [depth] => 0
    [depth_relative] => 0
    [expanded] => 0
    [sort] => 0
    [parent_mlid] => 407
    [menu_name] => main-menu
    [delta] => 1
)
Array
(
    [parent] => main-menu:219
    [title_link] => 0
    [admin_title] => 
    [level] => 1
    [follow] => 0
    [depth] => 0
    [depth_relative] => 0
    [expanded] => 0
    [sort] => 0
    [parent_mlid] => 219
    [menu_name] => main-menu
    [delta] => 1
)
```

but when I render the block he still display the sons of the 'main-menu:407' menu items
--node 2
--node 3

How can I really change the config programmatically?